# MySql - Select 3 tables and exclude if

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 3 tables a, b and c. Table a and b will be standalone, while table c will receive the id from both table a and b.

What I would like is a query that would select the id from both table a and b. But it wouldn't select them **IF** they already(both) exist in table c.

Note: There would be multiple entries in all tables

Edit:

Table a and b will have one column, whilst table c will have too(thought it was implied, my bad).
A will have id, b will have id. But table c will have a_id and b_id

example tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/714a6/11

Comment: I think you need to add a simple example of what the tables look like with input data and a desired result.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks, tried looking at the edit but couldn't find any tools for it o.o I made an edit to try and explain it better. Thanks for the tip ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select a.id ,b.id from A a,B b WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM C
    WHERE
        a_id = a.id
        AND b_id = b.id
)
```

Comment: Look at edit, table c will have two columns to hold table a's id and table b's id

Comment: try this modified query

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
SELECT `id`, 'a' AS `tName`
FROM `a`
WHERE `ID` NOT IN (
    SELECT `ID`
    FROM `c`)
UNION ALL
SELECT `id`, 'b' AS `tName`
FROM `b`
WHERE `ID` NOT IN (
    SELECT `ID`
    FROM `c`);
```

Comment: This could be looking like the answer I'm seeking, however the table C will have two columns and not just one. As it will have to contain table a's id and table b's id. Look at the edit :)

Comment: And what is your desired result?

Comment: Thanks for your time, Anirudh's answer however did exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id,b.id from a,b where id not in (select id from c)
```

Comment: Your query has error `Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous` ;).

Comment: Look at edit, table c will have two columns to hold table a's id and table b's id